# PHP/CakePHP 3 namespace issue with ZipArchive

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am migrating a working app from CakePHP 2.6 to 3.0. which has now implemented namespaces so I ran into an issue with ZipArchive and had to use the global `$zip = new \ZipArchive();`

This led to an error with the `$zip->close();` method `ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object`

I saw an example where adding @ to the close would work but it was called the quick and dirty way.

What would be considered the cleanest way to solve this?

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $file_path = WWW_ROOT . 'files/supporting/';
    $filename =  $file->name;

    if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
    }
    $zip->addFile($file_path,$filename);
}
@$zip->close();
```

Comment: `ZIPARCHIVE` is not the class name. Mind your casing (even though it might be irrelevant for the language itself). Also use "use ZipArchive" at the top of the class file and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the `use ZipArchive;` and I now do not need the \ in front of `ZipArchive();` However I still need to use @ in front of the close but I do not know why it is needed

Comment: The logic of that snippet is flawed, this has nothing to do with namespaces. The most obvious problem is that the `close()` method would be invoked while there is no file open when `$files` is empty. Also you seem to try to add a directory, instead of a file, that won't work. Relying on implicit closing by calling `open()` also isn't the best idea.